# Display a product custom field value in Woocommerce admin email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have this code in my function.php, how can i dispaly this field value in admin mail order? Thanks!

```
//1.1 Display field in admin
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Name',
            'label' => __('customtext', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );    
    echo '</div>';
}

//1.2 Save field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** There is two very similar alternatives (the first one is better):

To display easily this product custom field values in emails (and in orders too) you can use the following code, that will save this data in order items, once the order is placed.

First alternative code *(the best new one that use WC 3+ recent CRUD methods)*:

```
// 1.3 Save custom field value in order items metadata (only for WooCommerce versions 3+)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $custom_field_value = get_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_custom_product_text_field' );
    if ( ! empty($custom_field_value) ){
            $item->update_meta_data( __('Custom label', 'woocommerce'), $custom_field_value );
    }
}
```

… or …

The other alternative *(the old one updated)*:

```
// 1.3 Save custom field value in order items meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta', 20, 3 );
function add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $values['data']->get_id(), '_custom_product_text_field', true );
    if ( ! empty($custom_field_value) )
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, __('Custom label', 'woocommerce'), $custom_field_value );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

On orders you will get that (for both):

[image]

On emails you will get that (for both):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But, unfortunately, this decision did not work for me. Can there be any other solutions? Thank you

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Sorry, but I can not understand why this value is not displayed in email.

Comment: in any case, I appreciate your help, thank you very much.

Comment: @Harry I have updated my answer… You have now 2 alternatives and both will work for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now

```
//1.1 Display custom field 
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => 'text',
            'label' => __('Custom', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );    
    echo '</div>';
}

// 1.2 Save this field in admin
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));

}

// 1.3 Save custom field value in order items meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta', 20, 3 );
function add_custom_field_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $values['data']->get_id(), '_custom_product_text_field', true );
    if ( ! empty($$custom_field_value) )
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, __('Custom label', 'woocommerce'), $custom_field_value );
}
```

Comment: There is an error on the code with `if ( ! empty($$custom_field_value) )` that has 2 `$$` instead of one… I have updated my answer and I have added a better and modern alternative. Both will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! You helped me a lot!